# MongoDB getMore slow down find operation

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

On my mongodb, find query takes 0.079767814s to return matching documents. it returns total `"nReturned": NumberInt(5709),` and also perfectly execute index plan.

See below log

```
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"is_deleted"=>false, "user_role"=>{"$in"=>[6]}, "app_master_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('567b757e5659a66e5705b427')}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>-1}}

MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.079767814s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.getMore | STARTED | {"getMore"=>378139582621, "batchSize"=>0, "collection"=>"users"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.getMore | SUCCEEDED | 4.186633778s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 being removed from the cluster.
MONGODB | Server localhost:27017 elected as primary in rs0.
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.getMore | STARTED | {"getMore"=>378139582621, "batchSize"=>0, "collection"=>"users"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | everything_civic_production.getMore | SUCCEEDED | 2.669569172s
```

See `getMore` line in above log. it takes `4 seconds`

Can anyone help me to understand this odd behaviour?

Comment: A `getMore` is the actual "fetch" operation on the cursor. How many results are actually being retrieved? Also the `batchSize` appears to be overridden, and this would have been done somewhere in setting options on the cursor. Ideally you want a reasonable `batchSize` that is appropriate to the number of results intended to fetch.

Comment: @NeilLunn from where we have to set `batchsize`? total 5709 results should be fetched? How we can expedite fetching in such case?

Comment: The thing is that with a cursor, you most likely do not want all documents _at once_, since you iterate over said cursor. With the settings you have now, your application blocks until _all_ 5709 are loaded from disk and returned to your application. With a batch size of say 10, the application would continue as soon as the first 10 documents are loaded. The driver takes care of loading the next batch and the next, either until the result set is exhausted, or the cursor is closed or times out.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Is it meaningful if not use cursor? and some other way to fetch all 5709 records? What happens if i keep batch size 10000 to load all document in a once?

Comment: Not using a cursor rarely makes sense. If you want to do a calculation over all matching docs, use the aggregation framework. Aside from that: Do the maths. 4.186633778 / 5709 is less than a millisecond/doc, and that is for locating, loading and transferring all of them. Which is not slow in my book. Really depends what you want to do. Maybe you should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36527365/edit) and show us the query and describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GBD I know this is an old question but do you remember the solution (if you found one)? We are currently having the same/simialr issue.